# How to create mutually dependent objects safely?

Tags: java

Suppose I have the following two classes to start off with:

```
public class Game {
    private final Player self;
    private final Player opponent;

    public Game(final Player self, final Player opponent) {
        this.self = Objects.requireNonNull(self);
        this.opponent = Objects.requireNonNull(opponent);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Player {
    private final String name;

    public Player (final String name) {
        this.name = Objects.requireNonNull(name);
    }
}
```

Now I have discovered that I need access to the other players (thus to the `Game` object) in my `Player` class.

One way to do it is the following, add this to the `Player` class:

```
    private Game game;

    public void setGame(final Game game) {
        this.game = Objects.requireNonNull(game);
    }
```

However now it breaks immutability of the `game` object, are there ways to preserve immutabiity of mutually created objects?

Or do I need to resort to manually imposed mutability and safety (from a regular client perspective, not from a multithreaded synchronization perspective)? Such as throwing an exception whenever someone attempts multiple `setGame`.

To summarize, this is the mutual dependency I am trying to solve:

```
Player playerSelf = new Player(/* non-existing game */, "Self");
Player playerOpponent = new Player(/* non-existing game */, "Opponent");
Game game = new Game(playerSelf, playerOpponent);
```

versus

```
Game game = new Game(/* non-existing player */, /* non-existing player */);
Player playerSelf = new Player(game, "Self");
Player playerOpponent = new Player(game, "Opponent");
```

Does there exist a Pattern such as for example the Builder Pattern which aids against an explosion of constructor arguments, which could be solved in a way that breaks immutability if one wanted to avoid the exposion without using the Builder Pattern?

Comment: adding the `Game` object to the `Player` object does **not** *"break immutability of the game object"* It creates a circular reference which is what you should really be concerned about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you have a circular dependency, *break it*. It will help reduce your code's coupling, increase testability, and keep you sane. Why does `Player` need access to the other player in the first place? You might be trying to put too much functionality into it. Perhaps you could move that into the `Game`? Or into, say, a `Strategy` that's inserted into the `Player` object?

Also, bear in mind that immutability isn't always the answer. Some things, like the game state, are inherently mutable. Trying to shoehorn them into immutable objects is bound to make life miserable.

Comment: I'm glad this apparently was useful! What solution did you end up with?

Comment: Nothing so far yet, but I understood that I was about to do something which would cause trouble in the future hence this question... What I do have currently is that I have one Player, which needs to attack "the other player", hence I need to get hold of him in some way or another.

Answer (score 3):

### Immutablity is a great goal, but 100% immutability is really hard in Java:

Erlang makes every data structure immutable, which is great when the language supports it at that level. Unfortunately Java doesn't support this at the level that it needs to make it effortless and painless.

#### That said there are multiple solutions to this construction ordering:

Following something similar to the MVC pattern where the `Game` and `Player` objects don't even know about each other at all is probably your best solution. But it is the most complex and probably more code than is feasible for an answer here. I might post another answer on that solution by itself, until then.

Here are just a couple of the **simpler** solutions.

#### Inner Class Solution :

In this solution, the inner class always has an implicit reference to its outer class. There is no need to pass in the `Game` object because it is always in scope of the instances of the `Player` class.

```
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;

public class Q23726363B
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final Game game = new Game(args[0], args[1]);
    }

    public static class Game
    {
        private final Player p1;
        private final Player p2;

        public Game(@Nonnull final String p1, @Nonnull final String p2)
        {
            this.p1 = new Player(p1);
            this.p2 = new Player(p2);
        }

        public class Player
        {
            private final String name;

            private Player(@Nonnull final String name) {this.name = name;}

            public Game getGame() { return Game.this; }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Factory Method Solution:

Make the Game object the Player object factory. By making the constructors of both objects `private` you can guarantee that they are constructed correctly and make references *functionally immutable* by not providing a way to change them publicly.

Use a `FactoryMethod`, something like the following:

```
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;

public class Q23726363A
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final Game game = Game.startGame(args[0], args[1]);
    }

    public static class Game
    {
        public static Game startGame(@Nonnull final String playerOneName, @Nonnull final String playerTwoName)
        {
            final Player p1 = new Player(playerOneName);
            final Player p2 = new Player(playerTwoName);
            final Game game = new Game(p1, p2);
            p1.setCurrentGame(game);
            p2.setCurrentGame(game);
            return game;
        }

        private final Player player1;
        private final Player player2;

        private Game(@Nonnull final Player player1, @Nonnull final Player player2)
        {
            this.player1 = player1;
            this.player2 = player2;
        }
    }

    public static class Player
    {
        private final String name;
        private Game currentGame;

        private Player(@Nonnull final String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        private void setCurrentGame(@Nonnull final Game currentGame)
        {
            this.currentGame = currentGame;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Notes:

You might be tempted to create the `Player` objects in the `Game` constructor and pass `this` into the `Player` objects constructors to set the reference to the `Game` object.

Resist this temptation, this is called *leaking the `this` reference* which in the constructor is *bad* because it loses all the guarantees that the `Game` object is completely formed.

Also both of these solutions still have a circular dependency on each other.

The first isn't so bad because the Player class is an inner class of Game. The second is a simple but naive solution that works for small scale applications but not for larger more complex applications.